# why does excel/macro show boolean as -1?

Tags: excel, boolean, vba

Excel has started showing boolean answers form my macro function as a number

`TRUE` as `-1`,
`FALSE` as `0`

yesterday it showed then as `TRUE`  or `FALSE`.

Does Anybody know how to change that back? I have no idea what I changed.

Code:

```
Function VBARound(N As Double, Optional NumPlaces As Long = 0) As Double
    'VBARound = Round(N, NumPlaces)
    VBARound = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Function VBARound(N As Double, Optional NumPlaces As Long = 0) As Boolean
```